# Getting error "missing '=' after attribute name" when using PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

What does this error mean when trying to run a php script that's suppose to send an email?

> .local postfix/sendmail[3921]: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 690: missing '=' after attribute name: "??5:wq?:q!?  "

Comment: Why did your title say there was no error message when the actual question clearly shows one?

Comment: All help is greatly appreciated, I configure my php and apache files according to some online blogs that has work for others and still no luck. I'm just learning php and following a tutorial.

Comment: It means there's something wrong with your sendmail configuration, and SO is probably not the right place for this; try [Unix.SE] or [SF]?

Comment: My bad. I starting writing it before I actually went to the log files.

Answer (score -2):

there is error in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` at line 690 - there is missing  '=' after attribute name: "??5:wq?:q!? "

edit that file, fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Alex i was  being sarcastic but its like error is shouting what's wrong